# Django do not render ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I am working on a little project on Django, I have had some issues on rendering ModelForm. In main.html tag {{form.ad_p}} doesn't seem working. I only see "Save" button and don't see any ModelForm fields.

If I put below code to shell

```
 form = AddPath()
    form.as_p()
```

I see:

```
form.as_p()
u'<p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input id="id_name" maxlength="200" name="name" type="text" /></p>\n<p><label for="id_route_data">Route data:</label> <textarea cols="40" id="id_route_data" name="route_data" rows="10">\r\n</textarea></p>'
```

Can you explain, what am I doing wrong?

I already searched on stackoverflow, but same problem hasn't been resolved. I hope, I'll be more lucky

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Path(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length='200')
    route_data = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

from google_maps.forms import AddPath


def index(request):

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    form = AddPath()
    return render_to_response('main.html', args)


def add_path(request):

    #me = request.user
    me = 'test'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddPath(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tmpForm = form.save(commit=False)
            tmpForm.user = me
            tmpForm.save()
            return HttpResponse('Saved')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(form.errors)
```

main.html

```
{% extends 'basis.html' %}

{% block leftbar %}

        <form action={% url 'add_path' %} method="post"> 
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="hidden", id="coordinate" name="coordinate"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have added the form to the template context in `index`.

Comment: Yeap, i forgot add <pre>args['form'] = form</pre> to <pre>index</pre> I should be more observant. Thx for help.